# Installing only Ubuntu on a dual boot computer

Tags: ubuntu

I have a dual boot computer running Windows 10 and Ubuntu (two partitions on my hard drive). The boot program is Grub2.

I also have a USB disk with Ubuntu install files on. What I want to do, is remove Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and just install the Ubuntu from install files on the USB. What is the process to follow? I'm a bit afraid of re partitioning in Windows and then finding I've mistakenly uninstalled Grub2 and can't launch?

Answer (score 3):

There's an [excellent answer over on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/794/19872) which walks through the whole process of removing the existing Windows partition from within Ubuntu using `GParted`, and then updating the Grub bootloader, although it finishes by recommending *not* removing Windows entirely, but instead shrinking the Windows partition down to minimum size and then growing Ubuntu into the reclaimed space.

I can think of a few reasons why this could be useful—BIOS/firmware updates for your computer for one, especially given [Meltdown and Spectre's recent impact](https://spectreattack.com/)—and you will probably only need to retain around 10-20GiB to do so.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a great article! Just a question on it, how do I then go about uninstalling the current Ubuntu and making the partition size for Linux bigger? Do I just delete the partition (with Grub)? Will I be able to boot from the USB and then when I install the new Ubuntu it will pick up Windows in the boot menu?

Comment: In that simpler scenario, just boot from your USB installer and when prompted to partition, either accept the automatic option (which will remove all existing partitions), or partition manually and delete the existing Windows partition(s), then resize the Ubuntu partition and flag it to be formatted prior to install.

However, I'd personally recommend going with the linked answer and remove Windows and resize the existing partition. I'll wager there are more than simply just one single Windows partition, and there may be recovery and EFI partitions in there too.

Measure twice, cut once!